# how to update two table from one query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to update two tables from a single MySQL query?

Comment: Please give a better example of what you are looking to do, if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`update` statement**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) has a multi-table syntax, which you should be able to use -- depending what/how you want to update.